# Why is the image size of my vector PDF halved in the XCode asset catalog?

Tags: ios, xcode, assets

I'm running XCode 8 and attempting to add vector PDF files to my asset catalog, with the Scales property set to 'Single Scale' on the image set. The size of my PDF file is 50px x 50px. When I drag it into the asset catalog, the image size in the properties pane appears as 25 x 25 pixels.

When I was using Individual Scales, the PNG files that I dragged in showed their image size as exactly matching the size of the PNG file. i.e. A 50px x 50px PNG dragged into the asset catalog had an image size in the properties pane of 50 x 50 pixels.

Can someone explain why the image size for Single Scale PDF files appears to be halved?

Comment: Sharing some code snippet would help us to provide you with a better answer.

Comment: There's no code to share. This is a question about the XCode IDE and the asset catalog. The file size is 50px x 50px. When the file is dragged into an image set inside the asset catalog, the properties pane shows the image size as 25px x 25px.

Comment: When I drop a PDF file in the asset, the size does not show in the property pane. The size does show when I drop a PNG. Are you sure you are dropping a vectorized PDF ?